# What is BROWSER_ONLY option in ifcfg-* network configuration files?

Tags: networking, rhel, configuration, networkmanager, ifconfig

In my RHEL 7 minimal installation with Virtualization profile I found that interfaces configured with network manager(s) contain `BROWSER_ONLY=no` option, which is always set to `no` by default. Server is currently offline, so I won't post entire config, but this is from "regular", physical WAN facing interface `enp5s0` (`eth0`). When i configured another physical NIC using `nmtui`, the same option appeared. I've seen it in many config files posted online.

Now, if I don't know it, then probably I don't need it. Of course that's not the case, this is purely out of curiosity. Does the name literally mean "this interface is only for web browser-related traffic"? I can see how that would make sense with dedicated physical card, possibly VPN/IPSEC, meant only for safe browsing, maybe online banking, stock exchange(sic.), finance.

**Research:**

- all duckduckgo searches return content of ifcfg-* files that contain this option by default set to "no". I've tried searching for a phrase "BROWSER_ONLY=yes" to no avail
- neither of IFCFG(8), IP(8), NETWORKS(5) `man` pages reveal that information
- `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysconfig.txt` describes most of the options that go into `ifcfg-*` files for different types of connection, however there's no mention of `BROWSER_ONLY`
- briefly browsed through http://linux-ip.net/ that contains IP Command reference `ip-cref.ps`, to which `man ifcfg` refers and which I didn't find on my system
- and of course here, on Stack Exchange
- `grep -R BROWSER /usr/share/doc/*`, `info --apropos=BROWSER_ONLY` - guess what...
- haven't tried changing it to `yes` yet, however I doubt to see any difference, unless the interface will stop working altogether

Does it mean absolutely no one is using it? Is it some hidden or reserved for future use option?

<sub>I'm torn between posting this question in Unix&Linux and Server Fault. Not sure where it fits better.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [NetworkManager docs](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-ifcfg-rh.html#id-1.2.9.7.17) that suggests this setting is only used if you also configure proxy settings, i.e. you have `PROXY_METHOD=auto` present, and then determines whether the proxy settings are for everything of just browsers, however they think they can distinguish that. The default is `no` already.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for providing that link, I see it explains all(?) the variables that go into `network-scripts` files; very useful resource. Now I'll sleep better...